# Using differentials to approximate a function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, approximation

So I have a homework problem that I cannot figure out. I am supposed to approximate the value of $\sqrt{(4.98)^2-(3.03)^2}$ using differentials.
What I have so far is $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2-y^2}$$ 
$$\Delta f=f(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)-f(x,y)$$
$$df= \frac {\delta f}{\delta x}dx+\frac {\delta f}{\delta y}dy$$
Can I do this?
$$ df=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}dx-\frac {y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}dy$$
$$\sqrt{(5-.02)^2-(4-.97)^2}$$
$$ df=\frac{5}{\sqrt{5^2-4^2}}(-.02)-\frac {4}{\sqrt{5^2-4^2}}(-.97)$$
$$df=\frac{-5}{3}(.02)+\frac 43(.97)$$
$$df\approx 1.26 $$

I have the solutions manual and it says the answer should be $3.95$.

What did I do wrong, and how can I get to their answer?

I appreciate any help that anyone has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at it again I realized this
$$ df=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}dx-\frac {y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}dy$$
With $x=5,\Delta x=-.02,y=3,\Delta y=.03 $
$$f(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)=\sqrt{(5-.02)^2-(3+.03)^2}$$
$$ df=\frac{5}{\sqrt{5^2-3^2}}(-.02)-\frac {3}{\sqrt{5^2-3^2}}(.03)$$
$$df=-.0475$$
$$df\approx\Delta f$$
$$f(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)=\Delta f+f(x,y)$$
$$f(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)\approx3.9525$$

Comment: That's what I'm saying..

Answer (score 0):

So, in your example $x=5,\ \Delta x=-.02$, and I guess $y=3$ and $\Delta y=.03$. So, try with $y=3$.

Aand.. you should clarify the question. Maybe they want only to compute $\sqrt{(4.98)^2-(3.03)^2} - \sqrt{5^2-3^2}$.